# Cannot install node-sass dependancy

Tags: javascript, dependencies, npm-install, node-sass

I try to install all dependencies in the project Ive cloned from repo but it fails on `node-sass`. I use OS Ubuntu 14.04.
This is an error log Ive received:

> (

```
node) child_process: options.customFds option is deprecated. Use options.stdio instead.
make: Entering directory `/home/maras/Documents/eCodile/debtorcare/client/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/binding/binding.o
In file included from ../binding.cpp:7:0:
../sass_context_wrapper.h:10:3: error: ‘uv_work_t’ does not name a type
   uv_work_t request;
   ^
../sass_context_wrapper.h:20:3: error: ‘uv_work_t’ does not name a type
   uv_work_t request;
   ^
../binding.cpp:13:20: error: variable or field ‘WorkOnContext’ declared void
 void WorkOnContext(uv_work_t* req) {
                    ^
../binding.cpp:13:20: error: ‘uv_work_t’ was not declared in this scope
../binding.cpp:13:31: error: ‘req’ was not declared in this scope
 void WorkOnContext(uv_work_t* req) {
                               ^
../binding.cpp:19:22: error: variable or field ‘MakeOldCallback’ declared void
 void MakeOldCallback(uv_work_t* req) {
                      ^
../binding.cpp:19:22: error: ‘uv_work_t’ was not declared in this scope
../binding.cpp:19:33: error: ‘req’ was not declared in this scope
 void MakeOldCallback(uv_work_t* req) {
                                 ^
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/binding.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/maras/Documents/eCodile/debtorcare/client/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/maras/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-58-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/maras/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/bin/node" "/home/maras/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/maras/Documents/eCodile/debtorcare/client/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v5.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed
Debtorcare@0.0.0 /home/maras/Documents/eCodile/debtorcare/client
├─┬ gulp-jade@0.3.0
│ └─┬ event-stream@3.0.20 
│   ├── map-stream@0.0.6 
│   └── split@0.2.10 
└─┬ gulp-uglify@0.1.0
  ├── clone@0.1.19 
  └─┬ event-stream@3.0.20 
    ├── map-stream@0.0.6 
    └── split@0.2.10 

npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON Debtorcare@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON Debtorcare@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON Debtorcare@0.0.0 No license field.
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-58-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/maras/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/bin/node" "/home/maras/.nvm/versions/node/v5.5.0/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-sass@0.7.0 install: `node build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@0.7.0 install script 'node build.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/maras/Documents/eCodile/debtorcare/client/npm-debug.log
```

I tried to remove .node_modules file , restart etc but It didnt work. Has anyone any ideas what could be wrong here?

Comment: the issuse was diiscused here https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/217

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked.

Comment: @Marek, Could you please add this as an answer and mark it correct?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the following command to install node sass .

sudo npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass

Answer (score 3):

I am into the same error and along, I am maintaining multiple versions node using NVM, I resolved this using the following commands,

Clear the cache, using the following command,

```
npm cache clear --force
```

Install node-sass dependencies using,

```
npm install --save-dev node-sass --unsafe-perm
```

Rebuilds node-sass but only if needed,

```
npm rebuild node-sass --unsafe-perm
```

Then, I could make my build successful. Hope this helps.